# Having trouble solving $\log (x − 21) = 2 − \log x$ for $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I'm having trouble with this problem:

> $\log (x − 21) = 2 − \log x$, solve for $x$.

I'm coming up with $x=-5$ but that can't be right.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}\log(x-21) & = 2- \log x \iff e^{\log(x - 21)} = e^{2-\log x}\\ \\ 
& \iff x-21 = e^2\cdot e^{-\log x}\\ \\ & \iff x-21 = \frac{e^2}{x}\end{align}$$

Can you take it from here? Remember, we must have $x>21$, or else $\log(x- 21)$ will not be defined!

**Note**: if you're working with $\log_{10}$, then simply replace every $e$ with $10$, and you're good to go! For any base, $\log_b$, you'd use $b$ where I've used $e$.

Comment: What base is the logarithm $\log$? If it's base 10, then you'd have $$x - 21 = \frac{(10)^2}{x} \iff x(x-21) - 100 = 0$$ $$\iff x^2 - 21 x -100 = 0 \iff (x - 25)(x + 4) = 0$$ $$\iff x = 25\text{ or } x = -4$$ We throw out $x = -4$ because we cannot take the log of non-positive numbers.

Comment: Thanks amWhy. I wasn't expecting such a quick response. This is a great community!

Comment: You're welcome, @Amos!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $\log x = \log_{10} x$, here are the steps
\[
\log(x-21)=2-\log x
\]
\[
\log(x-21)+\log x=2
\]
\[
\log(x(x-21))=2
\]
\[
10^{\log(x(x-21))}=10^2
\]
\[
x(x-21)=x^2-21x=100
\]
Now just solve the quadratic equation 
\[
x^2-21x-100=0
\]
\[
(x-25)(x+4)=0
\]
Thus the solution is $x=25$. We cannot use $x=-4$ as a solution because $\log(-4)$ is undefined. I hope this helps you understand.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Amos, anytime. Welcome to math SE!